# Suppressing toast from package in Android

Tags: android, logcat, toast

I'm developing an Android app and I'm trying to show some information with a `Toast`.
I used `Toast`s in other projects and everything works, but in this app, when the `Toast` should appear, it doesn't do it and Logcat shows the next message:
`Suppressing toast from package com.xxxxxxx by user request.`

I'm creating the toast with the next code:

```
Context context = xxxxxxx.this;
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

I tried to set the context with `getApplicationContext()` and `getBaseContext()` too, but doesn't work.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 27):

Go to the App-Info Screen of your application ( long click on the app and drag it to the top in Android 4.0) and make sure the "Show notification" checkbox is selected. Otherwise your Toasts will be suppressed.

Comment: What do you mean with "App-Info screen". Where exactly should you long-click and then drag?

Comment: Its the same screen when you go to the Android Settings -> Apps

Comment: It worked for me, however I can't ask users to do this after installing app when they download from store.